# Why Otto is not working?

Tags: android, otto

I am currently trying to install Otto into my project. Everything went as expected following the steps here http://square.github.io/otto/ but when I register my activities, I do not receive callbacks.

In my `App` class I have the singleton

```
private static Bus bus;

public static Bus getEventBus() {
    if(bus == null) {
        bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);
    }
    return bus;
}
```

Then in my `BaseActivity` class I have this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentView());
    App.getEventBus().register(BaseActivity.this);
}
```

This is pseudo code but really these are the only methods I have in these classes. I also have suspicion of my gradle so my gradle file looks as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "wallfly.io.wallfly"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am using Otto at work and it goes really well. However I cannot get it to work at home. I am lost as it seems no one else has encountered this problem. Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure your proguard-project.txt so that it will not remove otto's annotations?

Comment: @user2616232 yes. i added the proguard rules inside my proguard-project.txt file. I am testing by trying to register the same object twice (which should cause a crash) but it does not cause a crash. This tells me that the class is not registering.

Comment: Tip: You do not need to use multidex. 1. Convert jars to gradle deps 2. Remove multidex 3.  Pick which deps you need: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: A complete source example would help answer your question.  Where is the callback you say is not being called?  Where are you posting on the bus?